# xCode not showing descriptive error in log console - just hex values

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

Here is my console of an error occurring in my applications(iOS).  i understand what the error is, but i don't know how to get a more descriptive trace of **where** this is in my code.  Before iOS5 and the new xCode, i would be pointed to the line of error in my code.  Now most times all i see is a hexadecimal output, and sometimes i get a short descriptive output like shown below.

`2011-11-14 09:37:42.868 AppName[916:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'`

`*** First throw call stack:
(0x343288bf 0x345781e5 0x343287b9 0x343287db 0x3779ef1f 0x50cd 0x3428722b 0x4edb 0x4fe9 0x5059 0x3175 0x41f1 0x3770a7ff 0x37708f9d 0x376fb941 0x3776d541 0x2bdf 0x377097eb 0x377033bd 0x376d1921 0x376d13bf 0x376d0d2d 0x30b03df3 0x342fc553 0x342fc4f5 0x342fb343 0x3427e4dd 0x3427e3a5 0x37702457 0x376ff743 0x2987 0x23d0)
terminate called throwing an exception`

**How can i get a more descriptive log output on errors like this? I would like to be shown/brought to the line of error in my code.  Hexadecimal output doesn't help me - or i don't know how to use it to my benefit.**

Answer (score 0):

You can print all of your item's attributes.

[image: This may help you]

EDIT:

Error descriptions will be at console, there are no more description to reach.